# Lengths and null_counts for children arrays of Structs in JavaScript apache-arrow

Tags: apache-arrow

I've encountered a peculiar case to do with null values of a `FixedSizeList` *within* a `Struct`.

**Little bit of context**

Using the `Builder` in the JS apache-arrow package seems to result in values that don't align with how I think the spec is laid out. We have a type that's a `Struct` with a single field that's a `FixedSizeList` (of length 2 with values of u64).

When we append `null` to the Builder, the resultant column should be `[null]`. What is strange to me though, is that the Builder specifies the top level node as having length 1 (as expected as there is 1 `null` Struct), but then the `FixedSizeList` node has `length: 0` and `null_values: 0`.

[The Arrow docs for Struct types](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html#struct-layout) suggest that the length of the children arrays should be equal to the length of the struct array.

So all of that is to ask,

**Shouldn't the FixedSizeList child array be of `length: 1` with `null_values: 1`**?

The builder looks like the following info (I've removed some fields for brevity):

```
{
    "length": 1,
    "finished": false,
    "type": {
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "foo",
                "type": {
                    "listSize": 2,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": null,
                            "type": {
                                "precision": 2
                            },
                            "nullable": false,
                            "metadata": {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "nullable": true,
                "metadata": {}
            }
        ],
        "is_any": false
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "length": 0,
            "finished": false,
            "type": {
                "listSize": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": null,
                        "type": {
                            "precision": 2
                        },
                        "nullable": false,
                        "metadata": {}
                    }
                ]
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "length": 0,
                    "finished": false,
                    "type": {
                        "precision": 2
                    },
                    "children": [],
                    "nullValues": [
                        null,
                        null
                    ],
                    ...
                }
            ],
            "nullValues": [
                null,
                null
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    "nullValues": [
        null,
        null
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you are correct.  Based on my reading of the spec I would agree the list array should have length 1.  I made a quick test with python and both the struct array and the list array have length 1.  Do you want to file a JIRA issue?  You may get feedback from the right people more quickly if you do so.

Comment: @Pace Thanks for checking that. We're actually using quite an old version of the JS package at the moment, so I don't want to waste anyone's time with a JIRA Bug report until I've had a chance to verify it still exists in a newer version of arrow. (Upgrading is unfortunately quite difficult in our application but is planned soonish.)

I'll see if I can set up a basic JS project with a new version of arrow and reproduce it.

Comment: I have tried to recreate it in apache-arrow 7.0.0 but it's been difficult due to the lack of proper documentation. I've opened a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-15651) but I don't know if I've tested it correctly